# How to fade out table selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When a tableview cell is selected in my app, it remains selected until a different cell is selected.

How can I make the highlighting of the tableview cell fade out after a second or two similar to Apple's Find My Friends app and the Find My iPhone app. When switching the distance from In Miles to In Kilometers you can see that the cell is highlighted and then the highlight fades out.

Comment: Instead of deselecting cell change the color of selected cell with animation. Check my ans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely you searched for an answer first?

Anyway...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: A little harsh, there are no duplicates on SO and this is now the top Google answer for `uitableview fade after select`. Your answer is efficient so I for one am glad OP asked the question